# Illustrator - I need the CMYK values of hundreds of colors in one file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk, rgb

I made a color chart by using the eyedropper to get colors from another file. When I go to get the CMYK values it only gives me a percentage. The Document Color Mode was RGB - changing it to CMYK didn't help.[image: Image of what I'm working on]
edit answer found: Was expecting CMYK values to be like RGB values, non-percentage numbers.

Comment: I do not see a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors in the color panel are just mixers. They don't **set** a color to RBG or CMYK. If you're in a CMYK document in File>DocumentColorMode -- You can just export the document to a pdf for print and boom, it's in CMYK. In your pdf export settings you can also confirm this by going to Output and selecting Color Conversion > Convert to Destination. Then make Destination Document CMYK. See screenshot below.

[image: Saving a PDF from Illustrator]

CORRECTION: In addition to what I said, please try this first. Select your colors and go to **Edit**>**Edit Colors**>**Convert To CMYK** Note that you may not see any drastic color changes depending on the color. You can do a test with RGB green (neon green) and either convert your document or do the Convert To CMYK command. You **will** see a change in color when doing this test.